# Remove all subsequent rows values up to specific text if specific text is equal to something Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have some data which I need to re-align properly.
The data has a main column which contains specific text and two delimiters. I am using the formula shown to split the text into the columns B:J.

So, if the column B contains "formed" text then I need to ignore all subsequent cell values and instead fetch the cells values that start from specific text - "yellow". This means all cells in red background will disappear and instead, the text starting with "yellow" will move and fit inside column C.

The problem I am having even with trying is figuring how to specify what to remove inside my current formula.

Here is what the data looks like
[image]

Link to my spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B6YVdMatgSkaXJpIZ3l8TxxzI8T1eviy_44rQrmJ04E/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

[image]

```
=if(left(join(" ",ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), "♦")), "♦", )),1,4)),6)<>"formed",INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), "♦")), "♦", )),split(substitute(join(" ", INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), "♦")), "♦", ))),join(" ",ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), "♦")), "♦", )),1,4)),"")," "))
```

use if(left()) to judge.if you don't want text3 in row 3, just change the 4 to 5 like :

```
=iferror(if(left(join(" ",ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), "♦")), "♦", )),1,5)),6)<>"formed",INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), "♦")), "♦", )),split(substitute(join(" ", INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), "♦")), "♦", ))),join(" ",ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), "♦")), "♦", )),1,5)),"")," ")))
```

Comment: Great formula but the challenge is that the data is not always going to stay spaced out in 4 columns which you removed in the formula. Formula has to use the word "yellow" to know where to start. Please see the spreadsheet.

Comment: Solved the above with `=iferror(if(left(join(" ",ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), "♦")), "♦", )),1,MATCH("yellow", C1:R1,0)-1)),6)<>"formed",INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), "♦")), "♦", )),split(substitute(join(" ", INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), "♦")), "♦", ))),join(" ",ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(A1,"❤️",0), "♦")), "♦", )),1,MATCH("yellow", C1:R1,0)-1)),"")," ")))`